# Facebook login always redirects to Liferay login page

Tags: liferay

I've created an app for Facebook login and gave client ID and client secret in *Liferay social login plugin*.

I configured OAuth Rdiredt URI in *Facebook developer* (advanced settings) as `localhost:8080/c/portal/facebook_social_login?cmd=token`. And in basic settings I have configured website URL as `localhost:8080`.

But it always redirects again to the Liferay login page without signing in.

Comment: You should add some more information (like your configuration), because otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: i already created app for facebook login and gave  clientid and client secret in liferay and redirect - uri in facebook  as [http://localhost:8080/c/portal/facebook_social_login?cmd=token ] but always it redirects again to liferay login page without sigin:(

Comment: You can always edit your question. Please include all relevant information, for example which properties you have set and what you have tried so far (you don't need to provide any login id or secret). And be careful when using formatting options like __bold__ and _italic_. It will discourage possible posters if you "shout" at them.

Comment: As i mentioned above i configured OAuth Rdiredt uri as "[localhost:8080/c/portal/facebook_social_login?cmd=token ".in facebook developer ----> Advanced settings and in basic settings i have configured website url as "http://localhost:8080" and configured CLIENT ID and SECRET ID in liferay social login plugin.

Comment: To make it more clear: You can always click on the [edit] link above and integrate all information into your question - like I did now for you.

Comment: I dont know how to make you clear,i have done the above mentioned steps only.

Comment: Which Liferay version you have this issue? I face same issue in Liferay DXP

Answer (score 0):

I think so you are doing facebook configuration from this below steps:

**Liferay Portal’s Control Panel → Configuration → System Settings*, and find the Facebook Connect module under the Foundation heading.**

You have to do below steps :

To override these defaults for a particular portal instance, navigate to Liferay Portal’s Control Panel, click on Instance Settings, and find Facebook within the Authentication section.

**Liferay Portal’s Control Panel → Configuration → Instance Settings → Authentication → Facebook**

Then you can go and check the facebook with login.

Other details for [configuration of Facebook integration in liferay DXP](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/facebook-connect-single-sign-on-authentication)